# Grunt | Error | Mac Only | Warning: spawn E2BIG Use --force to continue

Tags: macos, build, gruntjs, build-process, grunt-contrib-compass

I was handed a big grunt build process, and this seems to be the error coming :

> Warning: spawn E2BIG Use --force to continue

I found what the error is here : https://github.com/feross/standard/issues/40 and here : http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/. My error comes after a particular set of tasks have been executed (I checked this by plugging back and forth to find out the border line task after which this happens).

Following is the Error Stack where it fails (on grunt-contrib-compass task to compiles .scss files into .css files) when I run

> **grunt serve:all --appName=whitelabel --verbose --stack**

```
Running "compass:iea" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.iea exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="lib/sass", cssDir="app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/css", imagesDir="lib/images", javascriptsDir="lib/js", fontsDir="lib/sass/themes//fonts", importPath="lib/js/libs/vendor", relativeAssets
Warning: spawn E2BIG Use --force to continue.
Error: spawn E2BIG
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:151:15)
    at Object.exports.exec (child_process.js:111:18)
    at module.exports (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/bin-version/index.js:6:15)
    at module.exports (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/bin-version-check/index.js:15:2)
    at /Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/compass.js:75:7
    at configContext (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/lib/compass.js:145:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/compass.js:63:5)

Aborted due to warnings.
```

It happens on a grunt-contrib-compass task, but when I remove this task from the grunt file same error is shown on imagemin task, which implies that the error is purely system based (process arguments are too many)

```
Running "imagemin:iea" (imagemin) task
Verifying property imagemin.iea exists in config...OK
Files: lib/images/carousel/arrow_left.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/arrow_left.png
Files: lib/images/carousel/arrow_right.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/arrow_right.png
Files: lib/images/carousel/carousel-1.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/carousel-1.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.mobL.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.mobL.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.mobP.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.mobP.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.tabL.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.tabL.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.tabP.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/hero-idea.jpg.enscale.tabP.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/carousel/pager_current.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/pager_current.png
Files: lib/images/carousel/pager_default.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/carousel/pager_default.png
Files: lib/images/common/broken.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/common/broken.png
Files: lib/images/common/loading.gif -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/common/loading.gif
Files: lib/images/content-result-grid/result.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/content-result-grid/result.jpg
Files: lib/images/content-results-grid/result.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/content-results-grid/result.jpg
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Argentina.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Argentina.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Australia.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Australia.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Brazil.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Brazil.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Canada.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Canada.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/China.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/China.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Colombia.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Colombia.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/France.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/France.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Germany.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Germany.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/India.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/India.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Italy.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Italy.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/Switzerland.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/Switzerland.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/USA.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/USA.png
Files: lib/images/country-selector/japan.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/country-selector/japan.png
Files: lib/images/form/bg-input-focus.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/bg-input-focus.png
Files: lib/images/form/bg-input.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/bg-input.png
Files: lib/images/form/calendar.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/calendar.png
Files: lib/images/form/down-arrow.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/down-arrow.png
Files: lib/images/form/form-bg.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/form-bg.png
Files: lib/images/form/radio-selected.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/radio-selected.png
Files: lib/images/form/radio.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/radio.png
Files: lib/images/form/sprite.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/form/sprite.png
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.mobL.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.mobL.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.mobP.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.mobP.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.tabL.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.tabL.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.tabP.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/baseImage.jpg.enscale.tabP.high.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/hotspot-1.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/hotspot-1.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/hotspot-1.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/hotspot-1.png
Files: lib/images/hotspot/hotspot-2.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/hotspot-2.jpg
Files: lib/images/hotspot/hotspot-2.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/hotspot-2.png
Files: lib/images/hotspot/pointer.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/hotspot/pointer.png
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/arrow-left.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/arrow-left.png
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/arrow-right.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/arrow-right.png
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/clip-icon.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/clip-icon.png
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-1.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-1.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-10.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-10.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-11.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-11.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-12.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-12.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-2.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-2.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-3.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-3.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-4.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-4.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-5.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-5.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-6.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-6.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-7.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-7.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-8.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-8.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-9.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/media-gallery-9.jpg
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/play-icon.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/play-icon.png
Files: lib/images/media-gallery/slide-right-arrow.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/media-gallery/slide-right-arrow.png
Files: lib/images/plain-text-image/plain-text-image.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/plain-text-image/plain-text-image.jpg
Files: lib/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-1.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-1.jpg
Files: lib/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-2.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-2.jpg
Files: lib/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-3.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-3.jpg
Files: lib/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-4.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/related-content-list/related-content-list-4.jpg
Files: lib/images/rich-text-image-holder/richtext-image.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/rich-text-image-holder/richtext-image.jpg
Files: lib/images/rich-text-image/rich-text-image.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/rich-text-image/rich-text-image.jpg
Files: lib/images/search-result/truck.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/search-result/truck.jpg
Files: lib/images/social-share-print/print.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/social-share-print/print.png
Files: lib/images/social-share-print/share.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/social-share-print/share.png
Files: lib/images/tabbed-content/accrodion-arrow-active.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/tabbed-content/accrodion-arrow-active.png
Files: lib/images/tabbed-content/accrodion-arrow.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/tabbed-content/accrodion-arrow.png
Files: lib/images/tabbed-content/tab-arrow.png -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/tabbed-content/tab-arrow.png
Files: lib/images/video/youtube.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/video/youtube.jpg
Files: lib/images/video/youtube.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg -> app/whitelabel/js/libs/iea/core/images/video/youtube.jpg.enscale.full.high.jpg
Options: interlaced, optimizationLevel=3, progressive
Fatal error: spawn E2BIG
Error: spawn E2BIG
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at Through2._transform (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/index.js:59:12)
    at Through2.Transform._read (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
    at Through2.Transform._write (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
    at doWrite (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
    at Through2.Writable.write (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at write (/Users/vanan7/Documents/IEA/d2-front-end-training-repo/unilever-platform/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
```

In another project, that I asked a friend, the build process is much complicated (many arguments are passed), but this error isn't thrown there.

**This is happening only on mac machines and working fine on windows**.

Has anybody had this error before who could help? Or any one else you can? Thank you.